# Is there any way to import a .CAR file (WSO2) to Eclipse Developer Studio?

Tags: eclipse, import, wso2, wso2-esb

I need to import a .CAR file to Eclipse Developer Studio.

This .CAR file was generated from Enterprise Service Bus Project (wso2).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid but AFAIK there is no option to import a .CAR file to Dev Studio. CAR file is just a deploy able archive file, which packs deploy able artifacts into a single file.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you can extract the .car (using 7zip or renaming to .zip) and import the the artifacts one by one in your project. Note: many artifacts can be imported not using 'import' but using 'new->select from file'.

Comment: On my Mac I was able to simply run `unzip` on the car file. Didn't think a new answer was needed but thought to add to the one that gave me the right hint.

Answer (score 0):

With Integration Studio 8 and your project file ranamed from .car into .zip:

File | Open Project from File System... | Archive...

This allows you to edit all artifacts by means of Integration Studio's GUI panels though you cannot run the project. Don't even try the Export to Archive File in Integration Studio but after editing the artifacts, zip all of the their folders again in the filesystem to bring back the project .zip file, then manually rename it to .car and import it in WSO2.